# gawk NR and match issues

Tags: awk

I need to use regexs to parse specific lines of a data file.  My test command with match works, and my test command for specific line numbers work, but when I put them together, I get no output.

```
gawk 'NR==42 {print $0}' filename
```

prints out the entirety of line 42

```
gawk 'match($0, /([0-9]+)/, a) {print NR ":" a[1]}' filename
```

has a lot of print outs, but specifically has this output:
42:137674
So, my line 42 has a numeric match

```
gawk 'NR==42 match($0, /([0-9]+)/, a) {print NR ":" a[1]}' filename
```

doesn't print anything out, and I have no idea why.

I have a work around:

```
gawk 'match($0, /([0-9]+)/, a) {if (NR==42) print NR ":" a[1]}' filename
```

But I believe it's less performant, so would like to figure out why the other command doesn't work

EDIT:
Answered, I totally forgot about && between the NR and match

Comment: use `&&` logical and ?

Comment: omg, I'm so stupid and so burnt out, thanks, I've just been forgetting the &&, weird that it just dies quietly instead of throwing an error

Comment: The `awk` tool has a very forgiving syntax.  It will always try to concatenate adjacent expressions if it cannot turn them into one.  In this case, the match() returns a value of '1' which is appended to '42', so this pattern would only match on line 421.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer:** The solution to the problem is adding the and-operator which was missing:

```
NR==42 && match($0, /([0-9]+)/, a)
```

**What happend in the OP?**

Awk programs are generally written as a set of pattern-action pairs:

```
pattern { action }
```

which execute `action` when `pattern` is true.

The `pattern` used in the above reads:

```
NR==42 match($0, /([0-9]+)/, a)
```

which, due to the precedence order of the operators, actually resembles:

```
NR == (42  match($0, /([0-9]+)/, a))
```

Let us assume, for sake of example that we are on `NR==42`. The match function returns `0` or `1` depending whether or not a match is found. As mentioned in the OP, the `match` function returns `1` in case of `NR==42`. The `pattern` reads now:

```
42 == (42 1)
```

The operator of the form `expr expr` resembles string concatenation, so in awk, this is processed as

```
42 == ("42" "1")
42 == "421"
```

The operator `==` is a numeric operator if and only if both operands are numeric of nature. But `"421"` is a string, so it will convert the numeric value of `NR` to a string:

```
"42" == "421"
```

which is false and hence the `action` will not be executed.

**note:** the above action will execute if and only if the `match` function returns false on line `420` or true on line `421`